# Using the definition of the Fibonacci recurrence relation. $F_{2j} + F_{2j+1} $ to $F_{2k+2}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, fibonacci-numbers

How do I go from  $F_{2j} + F_{2j+1} $ to $F_{2k+2}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

$F_{2k+2}=F_{2k+1}+F_{2k}$

$=2F_{2k}+F_{2k-1}$

$=3F_{2k-1}+2F_{2k-2}$

$=5F_{2k-2}+3_{2k-3}$

The pattern is pretty obvious from here in terms of Fibonacci Numbers

Comment: I thought $F_{2k+2} = F_{2k} + F_{2(k-1)}$ ?

Comment: it should be $F_{2k+1}$ in place of $F_{2k-2}